# Regex to split a string, honouring quotes and preserving key=value pairs

Tags: c#, regex

Given an input string of:

```
V1 valueA=somethingA Version Data valueB="something longer" "diagnostic data"
```

How can I get a Regex query to split it into the constitute parts as per:

```
[0] V1
[1] valueA=somethingA
[2] Version
[3] Data
[4] valueB="something longer"
[5] "diagnostic data"
```

I've been trying to resurrect my long-ago last used regex experience, but instead this has been driving me nuts. The closest I have gotten to is this expression:

```
[\""].+?[\""]|[^ ]+
```

Comment: I made an edit which would also match longer sentences within the quotes. Have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to split, try to match all the parts you want. Here is the raw pattern (nothing is escaped):

```
[^\s"]+(?:"[^"]*"[^\s"]*)*|(?:"[^"]*"[^\s"]*)+
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E%5Cs%22%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%5B%5E%5Cs%22%5D*%29*%7C%28%3F%3A%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%5B%5E%5Cs%22%5D*%29%2B&i=V1%20valueA%3DsomethingA%20Version%20Data%20valueB%3D%22something%20longer%22%20%22diagnostic%20data%22)

Note that it's a general pattern, for your specific case (kind of attributes), something like this should suffice:

```
[^\s"]+(?:"[^"]*")?|"[^"]*"
```

To allow white-spaces around the equal sign, you can also write:

```
[^\s"=]+(?:\s*=(?:\s*"[^"]*"|\S+))?|"[^"]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

If one tells the regex parser to work backwards **on the text string** using the option `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` it makes the pattern easier to unravel. *Understand that the parser is working backwards on the string, but our pattern is still forwards.*

Simply look for a quote (in my pattern I use the hex value for a quote at `\x22` for easier reading) and if one is found match to the previous quote, then match to the next whitespace, otherwise when there is no quote just match all til the next white space.

```
[^\s]*                # We *may* have the proceeding xxx= so match til a space
  (\x22[^\x22]+\x22)  # Match the quoted stuff such as "xxx"
|                     # Or 
  [^\s]+              # No quotes so extract all text til the white space
```

The above pattern is commented so it needs `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhiteSpace` otherwise the pattern on oneline is

```
[^\s]*(\x22[^\x22]+\x22)|[^\s]+
```

**Results**

of your data

```
V1 valueA=somethingA Version Data valueB="something longer" "diagnostic data"
```

The `[x]` below are the group numbers to extract the data if applicable.

```
Match #0
          [0]:  "diagnostic data"
  ["1"] → [1]:  "diagnostic data"

Match #1
          [0]:  valueB="something longer"
  ["1"] → [1]:  "something longer"

Match #2
          [0]:  Data
  ["1"] → [1]:  

Match #3
          [0]:  Version
  ["1"] → [1]:  

Match #4
          [0]:  valueA=somethingA
  ["1"] → [1]:  

Match #5
          [0]:  V1
  ["1"] → [1]:
```

Notice that the matches work from the end to the beginning, so you may need to work backwards on the match array during extraction get the right direction. :-)